# lme4::lmer summary object contains double object with string

Tags: r, summary, lme4

take the following model as an example

```
library('lme4')
foo <- lmer(cty ~ hwy + (1|model), data=mpg, REML=F)
```

Now we can retreive the LogLikelihood of the model

```
sum.foo <- summary(foo)
LL <- sum.foo[["logLik"]]
LL
'log Lik.' -343 (df=4)
typeof(LL)
[1] "double"
```

Question: how can all this information be stored in a double object? There seems to be at least two strings in there, i.e. "log Lik." and "(df=4)". Is there a way to retreive the value of df from this object?

Comment: FWIW you can retrieve the log-likelihood directly via `logLik(foo)` (which retrieves an object with the same structure, i.e. a numeric value with a "df" attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LL` is really just a number (with attributes). The line you see when you print `LL` is created by the `print.logLik` function as you can see below:

```
getAnywhere(print.logLik)
A single object matching ‘print.logLik’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for print from namespace stats
  namespace:stats
with value

function (x, digits = getOption("digits"), ...) 
{
    cat("'log Lik.' ", paste(format(c(x), digits = digits), collapse = ", "), 
        " (df=", format(attr(x, "df")), ")\n", sep = "")
    invisible(x)
}
```

This is what gets called when you run `LL` but `LL` is really only one number (numeric vector of length 1). The `cat` function is what prints the `'log Lik.' -343 (df=4)` that you see on your console.

In order to get the df value you could do (as it can also be seen from the function above):

```
format(attr(LL[['logLik']], "df"))
```

See an example (from `lmer` 's documentation):

```
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
a <- summary(fm1)# (with its own print method)

> a[['logLik']]
'log Lik.' -871.8141 (df=6)
> format(attr(a[['logLik']], "df"))
[1] "6"
```

And as per @BenBolker mentions in the comment `format` only converts it into character.

```
> attr(a[['logLik']], "df")
[1] 6
```

Is probably better.

Comment: this is entirely correct, but I wouldn't bother with `format()` -- that's just for printing purposes.

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker . Valid comment. I noticed this but I thought it would be easy to figure out. But you are right it  is probably best used without it. (Great package btw).